# Deploy PipelineInspectionUser permission set error - License doesn't exist

Tags: opportunity-pipelines

- I enabled Opportunity Pipeline Inspection in my dev org
- Added the OOTB PipelineInspectionUser permission set to one of my existing Permission Set Groups
- I included in my deployment package `OpportunitySettings` which is where all the Pipeline config values are enabled

I kicked off a deployment from my dev org to GitHub and then CI job from GitHub to my `integration` sandbox.

This failed with three errors:

```
PipelineInspectionUser  PermissionSet       License doesn't exist
Opportunity             OpportunitySettings enableExpandedPipelineInspectionSetup
MyPermissionSetGroup    PermissionSetGroup  Cannot create permission set group components since the 
                                            following permission set names are invalid: 
                                            force__PipelineInspectionUser
```

How to I deploy this through my CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Opportunity Pipeline Inspector feature, released in V57.0 as a free add-on to existing Enterprise Edition orgs creates a new Permission Set License `Pipeline Inspection` in your org.

**HOWEVER**, Salesforce only did this for your **PROD org**, [not any sandbox orgs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_pipeline_inspection_enterprise_edition.htm&release=242&type=5) like staging, integration, qa, etc.

So, to make deployment work you have to `Setup > Company Information > Match Production Licenses` in each of your target sandbox orgs within your CI/CD/DevOps/Deployment process.

This step will create a `Pipeline Inspection` permission set license in your sandbox and the deployment will succeed.